# Multiple Application Service in a single ABP solution

Tags: abp

I want to create multiple Application Service. So I created two directories under src folder (WebPortal and IntegrationApi) and moved Application and HttpApi.Host folders(projects) into src\webportal and updated their project references. Then run the project, but I got FileNotFound(VirtualFileSystem) exception at runtime from BookStoreHttpApiHostModule.cs , following line:

`options.FileSets.ReplaceEmbeddedByPhysical<BookStoreDomainSharedModule>(Path.Combine(hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath, $"..{Path.DirectorySeparatorChar}Acme.BookStore.Domain.Shared"));`

Domain.Shared project is in the src folder, not in src\webportal, I think no need to move it.

How can we solve this error or should I create another Application project as named Acme.BookStore.Application.WebPortal in src folder or how should I go?